# Can two sequences of polynomials converge to a piecewise function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am having troubles considering the following scenario: Take two continuous functions $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$, and let $F=\max\left(f(x),g(x)\right)$ where $x\in [a,b]$. Find a sequence of polynomials $\{P_n\}$ such that $P_n\rightarrow F$ uniformly in $[a,b]$.

Given the continuity property of the functions in the domain, I can define a sequence of polynomials, say $M_n$ to approximate $f$ and $Q_n$ to approximate $g$ using the Taylor theorem (right?) around a point $c\in [a,b]$. If one defines:

$$P_n=\begin{cases}
        M_n & \text{if } f(x)>g(x)\\
        Q_n & \text{if } f(x)<g(x)
    \end{cases}$$

Is it correct to state that in the limit $P_n\rightarrow F$?

I am assuming that the sequences of polynomials will converge to the functions, I am sure that such approximation is possible due to the Taylor theorem, but I don't know if the convergence is uniform within the domain or if the selection of the point of expansion can affect the result, my thought process is that $c$ is an arbitrary point, so $P_n\rightarrow F$ should hold at every point in the domain (iff the pointwise convergence holds).

*note: ignore the case where $f(x)=g(x)$.

Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: The issue with your definition of $P_n$, is that it is not a polynomial in general.

Comment: Hmm, how can you say that there exists these polynomials $M_n$, $Q_n$? Taylor's theorem will not work in general. You could use Stone-Weierstrass; however, if you have that at your disposal you could just apply it directly to $F$, since it is continuous, and not bother with approximating $f$ and $g$ by polynomials.

Comment: A question that makes more sense would be to *assume* that there are such polynomial sequences $M_n$, $Q_n$ in the statement of the problem and then construct such a $P_n$.

Comment: is it possible to prove that $F$ is continuous? @{Jair Taylor}, you guys are absolutely right, I am off with my assessment. But the $\max$ function could induce some sharp edges in the function, say between $10\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$

Comment: I am very off in this one, my apologies, need to re check the material

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

(1) The sequence of polynomials

$$\forall x \in [-1;1],\ P_0 = 0,\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*,\quad  P_{n+1}(x) = P_{n}(x) + \frac{1}{2}(x^2 - P_{n}^2)$$ converges uniformly to the absolute value $A : x \mapsto \lvert x \rvert$.

(2) The $\max$ can be defined in terms of absolute value by

$$\max(x,y) = \frac{ x + y + \lvert x-y \rvert}{2}.$$

Comment: Does the $\max$ definition given above have a name?

Comment: I don't know it. By the way, this is not a definition. It is a formula that can be (easily) proven to be equivalent to the usual definition of the $\max$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check the examples, and also for that definition haven't seen that one before